# Best way to make footer always stretch to the bottom

Tags: css

My footer is a different color than the rest of the site and is roughly 400px in height. When there is not a lot of content on the page I have a white bar underneath the footer. I would like the footer to stretch to the bottom of the window if it needs to.

I do *not* want a sticky footer at the bottom of my page.

Also using Foundation framework, in case that matters.

```
<section id="footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
      <ul id="footer-links">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


#footer {
    padding:60px 0px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#6f6f6f;
    color:#aaa;
    height:100%;
}
#footer-links {
    list-style-type: none;
    width:100%;
    text-indent:0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#footer-links li {
    display:inline;
}
#footer-links a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:1.1em;
    color:#ddd;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-transform:lowercase;
}
```

Comment: Just a little side-note, instead of using `<section id="footer">` you might want to use `<footer>`

Comment: @Dex Can you check my Answer???

Answer (score 0):

Use sticky footer:
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Also theres a way for using twitter bootstrap to make it work with it:
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html

Comment: I don't want a sticky footer. The footer can be anywhere on the page

Answer (score -1):

You can easily just put the following things into your css.

```
html, body {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}

#header {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

But be sure that the padding-bottom is the height of the footer!

Comment: I don't want my footer to be on the bottom at all times.

Comment: I updated my post. Now it's like Dinesh Kanivu's, but with no need of the height attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Add Like this

```
body,html{position:relative; height:100%}
```

Footer CSS

```
 #footer{ position:absolute; bottom:0; height:400px; width:100%}
```

Comment: Is it possible without manually specifying the height? The height could change based on font size

Comment: @DEX height is important